# Having problems creating a program with javascript and html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I basically am trying to create this number guessing game. Whenever a user click on one of the circles, it is supposed to change colors and also, it is supposed to store that number and check whether it matches with the numbers in the array and if it does, the user wins, if not, the user loses. But i am having trouble making it. I was able to create a board that when u click on the circle it changes color and then i made a new project that i used for number guessing without using html just javascript to see if i could just understand the concept of making the game and it worked. However, after combining both of them together, the result was quite wrong. Now, not only do i get the wrong result after clicking on the circles, but also, the color of the circle does not change on clicking it. What do i do? and where did i go wrong.. Please explain. here are my codes. BTW the modify variable i used is for reducing the array to 3 elements so out of those 5 array elements, the user picks 3 only.

```js
 var Color="#F1C40F"; 
    function theFunctions(element){
    if(Color=='#F1C40F')
    {
    Color='#F00';
    }
    else
    {
    Color='#F1C40F';
    }
    element.style.backgroundColor=Color;
    var number= new Array(1,2,3,4,5);
    var time=new Array();
    var i;
    var modify= new Array();
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    modify[i]=number[i];
    }
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    time[i]=number;
    if(modify[i]==time[i]){
    document.write(time[i]+" Correct");
    }
    else{
    document.write("Sorry but you lost the correct order is "+modify);
    break;
    }
    }
    };
```

```css
   div#gameboard{
    background:#D35400;
    border:#999 2px solid;
    width:1200px;
    height:900px;
    margin:35px;
    margin-top:40px;
    padding:30px;
    }
    div#board{
    background:#EB984E;
    height:800px;
    width:800px;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:20px;
    padding:30px;
    }
    div.circleBase {
        border-radius: 50%;
        behavior: url(PIE.htc); /* remove if you don't care about IE8 */
     width: 130px;
        height: 130px;
        background-color:#F1C40F;
        border: 3px solid black;
    }
```

```html
<div id="gameboard">
    <div id="board">
    <div class="circleBase" onclick="theFunctions(1);">
    <p style="margin-left:48px; font-size:70px; margin-top:25px;"> 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="circleBase" style="margin-left:160px; margin-top:-136px;" onclick="theFunctions(this);">
    <p style="margin-left:48px; font-size:70px; margin-top:25px;"> 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="circleBase" style="margin-left:320px; margin-top:-136px;" onclick="theFunctions(this);">
    <p style="margin-left:48px; font-size:70px; margin-top:25px;"> 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="circleBase" style="margin-left:480px; margin-top:-136px;" onclick="theFunctions(this);">
    <p style="margin-left:48px; font-size:70px; margin-top:25px;"> 4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="circleBase" style="margin-left:640px; margin-top:-136px;" onclick="theFunctions(this);">
    <p style="margin-left:48px; font-size:70px; margin-top:25px;"> 5</p>
    </div>
    <div class="circleBase" style="margin-top:10px;" onclick="theFunctions(this);">
    <p style="margin-left:48px; font-size:70px; margin-top:25px;"> 6</p>
    </div>
    <div class="circleBase" style="margin-left:160px; margin-top:-136px;" onclick="theFunctions(this);">
    <p style="margin-left:48px; font-size:70px; margin-top:25px;"> 7</p>
    </div>
    <div class="circleBase" style="margin-left:320px; margin-top:-136px;" onclick="theFunctions(this);">
    <p style="margin-left:48px; font-size:70px; margin-top:25px;"> 8</p>
    </div>
    <div class="circleBase" style="margin-left:480px; margin-top:-136px;" onclick="theFunctions(this);">
    <p style="margin-left:48px; font-size:70px; margin-top:25px;"> 9</p>
    </div>
    <div class="circleBase" style="margin-left:640px; margin-top:-136px;" onclick="theFunctions(this);">
    <p style="margin-left:30px; font-size:70px; margin-top:25px;"> 10</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the `<script>` and `<style>` tags inside the root `<html>` tag. If you move them to inside the `<head>` tag then your code works. Delete the `</head>` and move it to after the closing `</script>` tag.

Although, your code currently overwrites everything on the page when the user selects the wrong sequence, try adding a css class to a hidden element to show the success/error messages instead.